# Firebase Query using emberjs

Tags: firebase, ember.js

I'm trying to sort a list of products from highest to lowest. The file json has been uploaded to firebase.

> *TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined*

thats the error i'm receiving.
My model is called "product" and it has the price attribute
Here is the code:

```
    sortHigh: ['product.price'],
    actions:{
      sortHigh(product) {
        sortedProducts: Ember.computed.sort('product', 'sortHigh')
        return this.store.query('product').sortHigh('price');
      }
    }                                                                  
 HTML {{action 'sortHigh'}}Highest Price
```

Comment: which file it is ?

Answer (score 2):

By default `store` is available only in route and controller. If you want to access store in any other place, then you need to inject to get it.

```
store: Ember.inject.service()
```